# libtool failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode4, libtool-xcode

I attempt to Create a Xcode-WorkSpace,there are there projects in it. Now the first Project is a static library  base on ZBar Code Reader.I already download the source code ,now I drag the finder named "src" into my first project. When I bulid it,here is the problem:

```
Libtool /Users/asset/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/huishow1-efdjffeirjufbndvocvtzkrzkwss/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libZBarTest.a normal i386
    cd /Users/asset/iPhone_Tmp/ZBarTest
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/libtool -static -arch_only i386 -syslibroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -L/Users/asset/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/huishow1-efdjffeirjufbndvocvtzkrzkwss/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/asset/iPhone_Tmp/ZBarTest/SDK -L/Users/asset/iPhone_Tmp/ZBarTest/SDK3 -filelist /Users/asset/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/huishow1-efdjffeirjufbndvocvtzkrzkwss/Build/Intermediates/ZBarTest.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ZBarTest.build/Objects-normal/i386/ZBarTest.LinkFileList -lxml2 -ObjC -framework Foundation -lzbar -o /Users/asset/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/huishow1-efdjffeirjufbndvocvtzkrzkwss/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libZBarTest.a

Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/libtool failed with exit code 1
```

Who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a missing dependency. I'm not familiar with the ZBar code reader but I'd imagine it declares dependencies on some system frameworks that you haven't yet included in your app? Look in the docs for ZBar to determine which frameworks you need to link to when including it. Typically when you get these types of libtool errors when you don't include a framework or other dependency.